# Is there a REST api of DashDB to export the content of a database in json format?

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, dashdb

I need to re-create a database from a DashDB Bluemix service into another. And I need to automate this procedure in bash scripts.
The best I can think of is a DashDB REST API that allows me to export the content of the entire database into json format (or any other format you can think of), and a corresponding API that allows me to re-import the content in a different database on the same service or on a different service, possibly in a different Bluemix space. Thanks.

Comment: Why not use the DB2 `export` and `import` commands?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39740976/dashdb-and-db2-load-operation

Comment: That's an alternative we are considering, however we would like do not add too many prerequisites to our automation.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to do a one time move and this is not about a continuous replication. In that case simply sign up on http://datascience.ibm.com, navigate to DataWorks, select "Load Data" from navigation panel (open it clicking top left) and then select Cloud Database as source type.

[DataWorks load data from dashDB to dashDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIdzz.png)

If you however still would prefer to write an own app or script that does the data movement and you want a REST API to export JSON data, then I recommend to write a simple R script that reads the data from a table (using ibmdbR) and writes it to stdout, deploy the script into dashDB (POST /home) and run the R script from your app/script calling /rscript endpoint: https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/wp-content/themes/projectnext-clouddata/dashDB/#/

Answer (score 0):

For Db2 on Cloud and Db2 Warehouse on Cloud, there is a [REST API](https://dashdb-txnha-flex-yp-dal09-104.services.dal.bluemix.net/console/api/index.html#/Authentication) available that allows you to export data from a table in CSV format (up to 100.000 rows) and then load the data back. It will require a few requests as:

- POST /auth/tokens
- GET /sql_query_export
- POST /home_content/{path}
- POST /load_jobs
- GET /load_jobs/{id}

I've implemented a client npm module for this API - [db2-rest-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/db2-rest-client) and you can export a statement result to a JSON file as:

```
export DB_USERID='<USERID>';export DB_PASSWORD='<PASSWORD>';export DB_URI='https://<SOURCE_HOSTNAME>/dbapi/v3'
db2-rest-client query --query="SELECT * FROM SRC_SCHEMA.SRC_TABLE" > test.json
```

Then you can transform that data into a .csv file and use the `load` job:

```
export DB_USERID='<USERID>';export DB_PASSWORD='<PASSWORD>';export DB_URI='https://<TARGET_HOSTNAME>/dbapi/v3'
db2-rest-client load --file=transformed.csv --table='DEST_TABLE' --schema='DEST_SCHEMA'
```